# Azure Search scalability

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

We are developing a mobile app that should scale for thousands of users and we are using Azure Search as our main storage. According to [Azure pricing model](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/search/) the query limits are set to 15 queries per second/per unit for the standard plan. With these limits and with a system that should scale with thousands of concurent users we would hit the limits pretty quickly.

In our situation is Azure Search not the right option when scaling for thousands of concurrent users? 
Would DocumentDB be a better option?

Thanks!

Comment: Their page does have a "contact us" option for larger volumes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting that you're using Azure Search as your primary storage, as it's not built to be a database engine. The storage is specifically for search content (type typical pattern is to use Azure Search in conjunction with a database engine, such as SQL Database or DocumentDB, for example), using results to point back to the "system of record" content in your database.

The scale for Search is specifically for full-text-search queries your users will generate. And Azure Search scales per unit, with each unit offering 15 searches / second. So, you can scale far beyond 15/sec if you buy more search units.

However: Don't confuse this with database engine queries. You asked about DocumentDB, so using that as an example: You can query far beyond 15/second with that database engine, and that scales independently. Same goes for any VM-based database solution, SQL Database, etc - they all can scale.

This really comes down to whether you need full-text-search at high volume. If so, great - just scale Azure Search to the number of units you need, to handle your request traffic. If you can do more database-specific searches, without driving your request through Azure Search, then you don't need to scale out as much, and can take advantage of the native database query capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to add to David's excellent answer - if your scenario is primarily search driven and you don't need to store data for purposes other than search and are OK with eventual consistency, then using Azure Search as the primary store may be fine.

Also, 15 requests per second query throughput of Azure Search is just a ballpark - it's neither a hard limit nor a promise. Depending on your data and query complexity, the actual throughput can be significantly (many times) higher or lower.

Comment: More details: the 15 QPS ballpark is per replica, you can have up to 6 replicas. You can also request larger search units that have ~4 times the performance. Ultimately this depends on your datasets and the types of queries you do, but we have customers that do several hundred searches per second with great latency.